# SCons: make Substfile depend on Install

Tags: scons

I generate some csharp wrappers using swig and install them to a directory.
After these files installed, I want to use `env.Substfile` to replace `public enum` with `internal enum`.
The thing is, no matter what I set the `Substfile`  to depend on, it always executes before the wrappers are installed

Here is a part of the script:

```
install = Install(bins, wrapper_bins)
script_dict = {'public enum': 'internal enum'}
for f in Glob(wrapper_dir.abspath+'/*.cs'): # tried also without the filter
    sub = env.Substfile(f, SUBST_DICT = script_dict)
    Depends(sub, install)
```

How can I make sure the `Substfile` will always be executed only after `Install` was done?

Here is the updated code (still doesn't work)

```
env['WRAPPER_DIR'] = "c:\\dev\\test\\"
script_dict = {'public enum': 'internal enum'}
for f in Glob(wrapper_dir.abspath+"/*"):
    sub = env.Substfile("${WRAPPER_DIR}/${SOURCE.file}", f, SUBST_DICT = script_dict)
    Depends(installed_bins, sub)
```

SCons version 3.0.1

Comment: So you want SCons to modify some files in place after they're copied?

Comment: @bdbaddog exactly. Is this not possible?

Comment: My next try would be to use the return values (=Nodes) of the `Install()` call and use those directly as source nodes for the `Substfile` method in each case. That should help *SCons* to figure out the dependencies automatically. Since `Substfile` is a proper *Builder*, your approach should actually work...in my opinion. I think using the `Glob` here is what makes *SCons* choke a little, so try to work around it.

Comment: @dirkbaechle, thank you. I'll try that and report back

Comment: @dirkbaechle Unfortunately it looks like the install doesn't return the files I need. I think I somehow need to build a custom builder in order to achieve what I want

Comment: It's not possible to have most build systems reliably change files in place.  (How would the build system know whether it's already changed the file in place on the last build or not)... That said, you can  substfile from the source location with a target of where you want the file to end up (target).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
installed_bins = Install(bins, wrapper_bins)

env['WRAPPER_DIR']='some path'
script_dict = {'public enum': 'internal enum'}
for f in Glob(source_path_for_cs_s+"*.cs"):
    sub = env.Substfile("${WRAPPER_DIR}/${SOURCE.file}", f, SUBST_DICT = script_dict)
    depends(installed_bins, sub)
```

Comment: Thank you @bdbaddog but that didn't work. BTW, I didn't see any `Substfile` that accepts source and target (and if it does, aren't they swapped on your suggestion?)

Comment: It's a builder.. .all builders accept target and source.  Assuming you want the output to go into WRAPPER_DIR then the order above is correct.  When you say it didn't work, can you provide more details. We can't help you without more details..